# Trigger listboxItem visibility from userControl in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I need when the UserControl inside DataTemplate stay invisible, the entire ListBoxItem stay invisible, but all i have tried is failed.

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Visual:uc_acessorio_fechado Acessorio="{Binding}"/> //when this element is collapsed, make the ListBoxItem collapsed
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>     
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your control sets its own Visibility, this may work:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Visual:uc_acessorio_fechado
                Acessorio="{Binding}"
                Visibility="{Binding Visibility,
                             RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBoxItem},
                             Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>     
</ListBox>
```

It won't work with a Style Setter, but e.g. with assigning a local property value.

---

Alternatively, you may use this:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Visual:uc_acessorio_fechado x:Name="uc" Acessorio="{Binding}"/>                        
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=uc}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```